# Bookmarks implementation logic django

Tags: python, django, api-design

I am developing REST API using django rest framework. Now I want to make a functionality to mark some ads as favorite. Here are some of my ideas:

1. creating new model Favorites, containing user id and ad id. So, mobile app will be fetching them from tables. However, making table containing foreignkeys only looked not good for architecture.
2. adding array field inside user model, and save ad ids inside. Tried using ArrayField from postgres-extensions, but I keep getting typeerror related with 'form_size'. Even though I removed 'form_size' from migrations files, as it is shown [here](https://github.com/primal100/django_postgres_extensions/issues/1), I get 502 error.

So, should I keep using ArrayField and try to fix that error?
Or creating table with 2 foreignkeys only looks not that bad?

Please, If anyone faced 'form_size' typeerror, help me.

Thank you.

Update 1.
Here is favorites field in User table

```
favorites = ArrayField(
        base_field=models.CharField(max_length=50), default=[], blank=True,
    )
```

I am importing these:

`````
````from django.contrib.postgres.fields import ArrayField

UPD 1.
`````

Comment: There's nothing wrong at all with a table containing only foreign keys. And the implementation will be simpler and safer. The array version will probably perform better at large scale, but that's unlikely to be relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can suggest 2 methods, but prefer the second one since it's simpler:
- Creating a new Model "Bookmark" is fine, you'll have foreign keys to the USER and AD models, and this will let you add an other attributes (like bookmarked_date, bookmarks tag...)
- Simply adding a ManyToMany attribute "Bookmarks" to the USER Model, this is easy and should be enough in your case